# cellForRowAtIndex method not getting called?

Tags: ios, uitableview

In my application I used two `tableViews`. For the first table all `delegate` and `datasource` methods are called. When I add the second table and call the method

`[self.tableView reloadData];`

`cellForRowAtIndex` method is not called.  In the second table, the number of sections is 1 and the number of rows is 5. I set the `delegate` and `datasource` for `tableView` programatically.

Comment: show the codez, then only you can get the soln

Comment: Is self.tableView referring to the 2nd table view?

Comment: Perhaps you have not connected the outlet to second table.

Comment: add the following asserts to your code (before the call to reloadData) and see what happens: `NSAssert(self.tableView, @"No tableview");
 NSAssert(self.tableView.dataSource, @"No datasource");`

Comment: @ Matthias Bauch :NSAssert(self.tableView.dataSource, @"No datasource"); at this statement app is crashed..and getting error as 
*** Assertion failure in -[TabViewController ClickOnViewOrder:]
On ClickOnViewOrder i wrote the NSAssert statements..

Comment: an `NSAssert` checks if the condition inside the parenthesis validates to true. If it does not it crashs your app. In this case self.tableVIew.dataSource is nil because you didn't set the dataSource of the tableView.

Answer (score 1):

It can be due to any of the below resons :

1. You have not connected the `outlet` to second table you are **reloading**.
2. You have not assign delegate as `yourtable.delegate= self;`

So if there is any of the missing case fix it.

Answer (score 0):

When `NSAssert(self.tableView.dataSource, @"No datasource");` is crashing, you haven't set the dataSource of the tableView correctly.

The `NSAssert` will crash your app if the condition inside the parenthesis of the assert validates to false (or 0, or in this case nil).

Wherever you create your tableView, make sure that you set the dataSource (and probably delegate too) correctly.

Regarding setting the dataSource correctly, don't make the mistake to set the dataSource to a newly created instance of your viewController. Most likely you want to use `self.tableView.dataSource = self;`.